# Trying to use Kqueue in linux mint debian

Tags: c, sockets, kqueue

I am Trying to use kqueue for doing an event oriented server in c when i compile my code it give me this error

fatal error: sys/event.h: No such file or directory

according to a tutorial that I am following to create the kqueue events that file have to be include I am new to events programming in C

Comment: Hi, you should provide more info... code, what have you tried etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`kqueue`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) is only present in BSD (FreeBSD / OpenBSD) and Darwin (Mac OS X / iOS) kernels. It does not exist in the Linux kernel.

The closest equivalents available on Linux are [`epoll`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) for asynchronous I/O, and [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) for file system watches.

Comment: Thanks do you happen to know a link to a good tutorial of epoll

Comment: Avoid using epoll directly. Use [libevent](http://libevent.org/); it's OS-independent.

Answer (score 1):

kqueue is a BSD feature.  you cannot use it on Linux.  the equivalent feature on Linux is epoll.

Comment: Thanks do you happen to know a link to a good tutorial of epoll

Answer (score 1):

If you want t try kqueue in any platform other than BSD, then https://github.com/mheily/libkqueue library is your way to go!! give this a try.